How Using Filter->Cell Value right menu option I can select 2 fields?
In Dbeaver Version 24.0.0.202403091004
Using Filter->Cell Value right menu option I can select 1 selection of current cell/value :

with filter like :
model_type = 'App\\Models\\News'

But can I select 2 fields and filter like :
model_type = 'App\\Models\\News' and model_id = 9

?
